# How to add new screen dimension for xrandr selection?

Tags: xorg

I'm using the GPU in my i3-3225 processor, an Ivy Bridge processor. 
The PC is connected through a KVM switch to the display.

When booting the PC with the display selected and On, I get the 1280x1024 resolution of my display.

When booting with the display off or not selected on the port, I get a resolution of 1024x768 @ 61 kHz.

What can I do to get the 1280x1024 resolution ?

I tried the xrandr recipe but I get the *xrandr: Configure crt 0 failed* error.

I know about the EDID thing. Could there be a way to save the current Xorg configuration as to be used as default even if the display is not connected ?

**EDIT:** Additional information

This is the output of xrandr --verbose I get when the PC is booted with the display connected:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 (0x138) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
Identifier: 0x137
Timestamp:  1212589
Subpixel:   no subpixels
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
1280x1024 (0x138)    0.0MHz *current
    h: width  1280 start    0 end    0 total 1280 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
    v: height 1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024           clock    0.0Hz
1024x768 (0x139)    0.0MHz
    h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
    v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock    0.0Hz
800x600 (0x13a)    0.0MHz
    h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
    v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock    0.0Hz
640x480 (0x13b)    0.0MHz
    h: width   640 start    0 end    0 total  640 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
    v: height  480 start    0 end    0 total  480           clock    0.0Hz
```

This is the output of xrandr --verbose I get when the PC is booted with the display is **not** connected:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 (0x138) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
Identifier: 0x137
Timestamp:  4495
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
1024x768 (0x138)   48.0MHz *current
    h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   46.8KHz
    v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   61.0Hz
800x600 (0x139)   29.3MHz
    h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock   36.6KHz
    v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock   61.0Hz
640x480 (0x13a)   18.4MHz
    h: width   640 start    0 end    0 total  640 skew    0 clock   28.8KHz
    v: height  480 start    0 end    0 total  480           clock   60.0Hz
```

Comment: *How* did you try the "xrandr recipe"? An example would help knowing what went wrong, because `xrandr` *is* what you want to use. You usually just use it to set to the mode you want to (as you say you know about the EDID thing, I suppose you know it provides the card with the list of supported modes and the preferred mode). The different resolution is just because the video driver will check across the connected displays for the supported resolutions -- if I boot my laptop with a display connected to the VGA port, I may as well as get 1024x768 on both, because it will mirror the screens by ...

Comment: ... default, and so it picks a video mode that suits both displays. If you don't have that monitor connected (not off, but not connected at all, even if it is off, it can provide the card with EDID data) when starting the video driver, that monitor won't, of course, be available to be taken into account when choosing the video mode.

Comment: What I tried with xrandr is described here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr. The only difference is that my display is named *default*, apparently. The motherboard has a DVI and VGA connector and the KVM is connected on the VGA connector. I don't know if I should specify VGA as output. Another thing I tried, without success, is to pick a modeline found in the xord.0.log when booting with the screen and try to use it with xrandr after booting without screen.

Comment: If a line shows in `xorg.0.log` when you boot with the display, it will show up in `xrandr` after you connect the display. Both X and XRandR will query the display for EDID data. And `xrandr` is updated in real-time, so once you plug the display, it will get the modes. Can you *please* share the *exact* command that gives the error above? And share the plain output of xrandr after connecting the display?

Comment: What do you mean by *connecting the display* ? I use a KVM switch. Do you mean connecting by switching the display or do you mean physically disconnecting and reconnecting the VGA plug at the back of the PC ? What I did with xrandr is the following: #cvt 1280 1024, #xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync, #xrandr --addmode default "1280x1024_60.00", #xrandr --output default --mode "1280x1024_60.00", screen flashes half a second and I get this "xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed"

Comment: The only way I managed to get the correct screen resolution was by restarting the lightdm service (I'm using Xubuntu). I also tried to execute *sudo Xorg :0 -configure* but I had an error and it stopped. When starting lightdm the Xorg.0.log shows that it went much far in the setup.

Comment: Oops, when restarting lightdm, the resolution is not changed. The console is in very low resolution.

Comment: have you tried setting one of the modes xrandr offers? If it uses the mode you want when you boot it with the display you want connected, then chances are that you don't need to add new modes. Please share the output of xrandr, both with and without the desired display

Comment: Also, by "connected" I mean "such that the computer in question can have a link with the display in question, that is, such that any EDID data reaches the video card". Just turn it on and set the switch to the desired computer

Comment: I tried and it worked. More precisely, I booted with the display connected and got 1280x1024 display and it is also showing up in the xrandr list. *xrandr --output default --mode 1024x768* did work. Setting it back to 1280x1024 worked also. The problem is that if the display is not connected when the PC is booted and I switch later the KVM to connect the display to the PC xrandr doesn't show the resolution 1280x1024 in the list. The best I can get is 1024x768 and it is 48Hz. Since the PC is a server it is often restarted with the display not connected. So I look for a solution to get 1280x1024

Comment: I don't understand why I can't create a new mode and switch to it with xrandr.

Comment: You're adding the mode *after* connecting the display, right?

Comment: Also, the reason I've been asking you to show some output for *several* times is that, unless your setup is rather special, you won't need to add a new mode *at all*

Comment: If it does not show the resolution you want in the list, care to, at least, share that list?

Comment: Yes I type the commands to add the mode when the display is connected but the PC booted with the display not connected.

Comment: Could this problem be related to the *nomodeset* parameter I have to add this option to the boot command in order get a display.

Comment: no. It is puzzling that you don't get new modes when you change displays. Try not having anything connected at all before connecting the second display and see if it updates the mode list. Also, try adding the mode *after* connecting the display.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I have only one display but it is connected through the KVM switch. The test I just did is to remove the KVM and connect the display directly to the PC. In that case I don't need the nomodeset option to boot. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12476464#post12476464 for more detailed information like listings of Xorg.0.log. Apparently, without the KVM, the Intel driver is loaded and used, and with the KVM, the VESA driver is loaded and used. Maybe I can force Xorg to load the Intel driver with an Xorg.conf file.

Comment: You can probably "force" Xorg to load any recent driver by not disabling kernel modesetting. Currently developed drivers for video cards (Intel, AMD radeon, nVidia) all rely on KMS to work. If you disable KMS, no wonder it falls back to VESA, and maybe that's why it does not even get the EDID information as it should. Try to focus on finding why does the screen go blank. Does the display tell anything like "unsupported resolution" or "unsupported refresh rate"?

Comment: In published the Xorg.0.log file on the ubuntu forums I obtained when booting without nomodeset. This shows that the Intel driver fails to connect to the display and get the EDID.  It could be the KVM that disconnects the display when the connection is temporarily cut by the PC when it reset the graphic card. So it is very likely a KVM problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by my KVM (TRENDnet TR-409K) switch that doesn't properly forward DDC/EDID information when the screen is connected to the PC and absolutly nothing when the screen is not connected.

As a consequence the Intel driver is unable to determin the screen caracteristics. I thus have to add the nomodeset boot option which disables the KMS system and thus screen resolution change with xrandr also. But at least the Intel driver is able to boot when the screen is connected and provides a max resolution of 1280x1024. When it is not, the Intel driver gives up and the VESA driver is started with a max resolution of 1024x768.

When I boot with the display directly connected to the PC (KVM removed) the Intel driver gets all the information it requires and I get many more display mode.

The KVM I used, which is cheap, is thus not good enough. A good KVM caches the EDID information provided by the display so that a PC connected to the KVM can obtain it even if the display is not connected to the PC. Such smarter KVM for desktop usage are more expensive of course.

BTW, I see the same display resolution problem when I boot my Windows 7 computer with the display not connected. When the screen is connected when it boots I get the correct 1280x1024 resolution, and when not connected when it boots, I get a max resolution of  1024x768. Now I understood why.

I ordered I new KVM switch (Belkin SOHO kvm switch) which is "smarter" and is said to cache the DDC/EDID information. I'll update this response with feedback as soon as possible.